# Andengine collision in Sprite and Sprite Center point

Tags: android, andengine, collision-detection

Andengine collision in Sprite and Sprite Center point.I have a balloon Sprite and target want to detect balloon and centerpoint of Target sprit.

Comment: Explain what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

Explain what exactly you want?Is this shooting  type of game?.Is target is movable or not?  If movable then  you want to know the ballon sprites pos then use contains() method to know that it is in target region or not.

Comment: Place all ballon sprites  in an array list. Check in Update handler these position.If you want to target center point of ballon then make your balon  anchor point to center.